# Angular 2 Material Design Autocomplete search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I got some issues on autocomplete on Angular2 Material Design which these are the things happened:

*When I type a character that is associated with the one I search it won't display on the autocomplete the specific character that I entered on the search textbox as shown in the picture below:

1. [When before typing on the search box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGMh9.png)
2. [When after typing on the search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIoZ3.png)

The second one is that when I select a specific list on the list of users it seems that it will display the `[object Object]` thingy and I don't know why it happens. See the picture below:

1. [When before selecting a employee on the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZIrG.png)
2. [When after selecting a employee on the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG4IY.png)

Here is my code below see if there's something that I missed or what.

**Angular Code:** *new-useraccount-components.ts*

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebServiceComponents } from '../WebService/web.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'new-user-account',
    template: `
              <md-card class="card-margin">
                <md-card-content>
                    <md-input-container>
                        <input mdInput placeholder="Select Employee" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="UserAccountCtrl" /><br />
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                        <md-option *ngFor="let userAccount of filterUserAccount | async" [value]="userAccount">
                            {{userAccount.username}}
                        </md-option>
                    </md-autocomplete>
                    <md-input-container>
                        <input mdInput placeholder="Username" /><br />
                    </md-input-container>
                </md-card-content>
              </md-card>
              `
})

export class NewUserAccountComponent{
    UserAccountCtrl: FormControl;
    filterUserAccount: any;

     async ngOnInit(){
        var response = await this.webService.getUserAccounts();
        this.userAccounts = response.json();
    }

    userAccounts = [];

    constructor(private webService : WebServiceComponents){
    this.UserAccountCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filterUserAccount = this.UserAccountCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(name => this.filteredUserAccount(name));
    }




   

    filteredUserAccount(val: string) {
    return val ? this.userAccounts.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s))
               : this.userAccounts;
  }
}
```

**AppModule:** *app.module.ts*

```html
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { WebServiceComponents } from './WebService/web.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserAccountComponent } from './UserAccount/useraccount-components';
import { NewUserAccountComponent } from './UserAccount/new-useraccount-component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UserAccountComponent, NewUserAccountComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ WebServiceComponents ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Sorry I'm just a newbie trying to play with this new framework.  Hopefully someone will guide me on how to fix this issue.  Thank you and Have a wonderful day ahead!

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't undestand the first statement that you described. For the 2nd. just use the `[displayWith]` *option* as described in docs.

Comment: @developer033, What i was trying to say is that when I focus on the search box it shows all the list of the users however when I try to type something on the search box all of the list are gone and also the even it is associated with the characters that suppose to be appears on the autocomplete.  On the 2nd picture when I type `a` it should suppose to appears the list [`ajqportal` and `admin`] on the list.  Hopefully this will suffice your question.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are quite clear if you read them closely enough:

- https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

You'll be especially interested in what it has to say under the title "**Setting separate control and display values**". It is not displaying your search result because you want to display something different than the `[value]` you've specified.

The other problem you are having is that when selecting an item in the list the actual value of that item is inserted into the search box. Since this is a `userAccount` and not the username, `[object Object]` is displayed.

Simply changing to `[value]="userAccount.username"` could solve both your problems. If this does not give you the desired effect, you'll have to use the `[displayWith]` attribute as explained in the docs.